# How to use the replace() method?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following project project setup:
 [**PLUNKR**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NhB1m0MGnDOHifXM2blH?p=preview)

If you select the first four words and press the `Highlight` button the text will be highlighted. However, if the first full length sentence is highlighted and the `Highlight` button is pressed, the main text will not get highlighted.

I don't quite understand why the highlighting feature works with a small sample of words but doesn't work with a lot of words highlighted.

Comment: I tried to have a look, but this Plunkr site doesn't make inspecting easy, and your example is far from minimal, so I gave up. Your question would benefit from having a *minimal* inline code snippet, where 'minimal' mean unnecessary Javascript, CSS, and functionality like the color selector being stripped away.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look into this. The files can be downloaded and tested on a local machine using the download button on the top right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work across lines because of your line breaks: `\n`

Either set the following css that affects rendering:

```
#myspan {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Or use an overkill regex in your `highlight` method:

```
word = sentword.replace(/ /g, "\\s");
```

Comment: That's great thank you. I was stuck on this issue as I didn't even know how to debug it when certain words selected were highlighted as expected and others not.